# Drop-down menu is not working properly

Tags: jquery, css

So I created this drop-down menu and it works great until I hover over the "Most Popular" title. When this event occurs the section's height remains at 0px when it should be 370px. I seriously do not understand why. Can someone help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>list</title>
    <!--links in font-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--links in jQuery-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
/* do not  include in production */
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
    }
    body {
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
        color: white;
    }
    .cards {
        background: white;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        border: #DDD solid 1px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
/* INCLUDE */
    #n-wrap {
        max-width: 950px;
        height: 590px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 auto 10px;
    }
    .n-titles {
        line-height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
        color: black;
    }
    .n-titles:first-child {
        background-color: #888;
        color: white;
    }
    .n-titles:nth-child(n+2):hover {
        background-color: rgb(96, 223, 229);
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .n-titles:nth-child(n+2):hover + .n-items {
        height: 370px;
    }
    .n-items {
        height: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        transition: height 0.5s ease;
        background-color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .n-items img {
        width: 25%;
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
    .n-items img:nth-child(2) {
        padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
    }
    .n-items:hover {
        height: 370px;
    }
    #highlight {
        background-color: rgb(96, 223, 229);
        color: white;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div id="n-wrap" class="cards">
        <div class="n-titles">FEATURED</div>
        <div class="n-titles">Most Popular</div>
        <div class="n-items">
            <img src="pseudo_img.jpg">
            <img src="pseudo_img.jpg">
            <img src="pseudo_img.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="n-titles">On Sale</div>
        <div class="n-items">
            <img src="pseudo_img.jpg">
            <img src="pseudo_img.jpg">
            <img src="pseudo_img.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="n-titles">Newest</div>
        <div class="n-items">
            <img src="pseudo_img.jpg">
            <img src="pseudo_img.jpg">
            <img src="pseudo_img.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100vh"></div>   
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //always have first section open 
            $(".n-items:nth-child(3)").css("height", "370");
            //highlight specific title
            $(".n-items, .n-titles").hover(function() {
                $(".n-items:nth-child(3)").css("height", "0");
                $(".n-titles").removeAttr("id");
                switch ($(this).index()) {
                    case 2:
                    $(".n-items:nth-child(3)").css("height", "370");
                    $(".n-titles:nth-child(2)").attr("id", "highlight");
                    break;
                    case 4:
                    $(".n-items:nth-child(3)").css("height", "0");
                    $(".n-titles:nth-child(4)").attr("id", "highlight");
                    break;
                    case 6:
                    $(".n-items:nth-child(3)").css("height", "0");
                    $(".n-titles:nth-child(6)").attr("id", "highlight");
                    break;
                }
            }, function() {
                for (var i = 2; i <= 6; i +=2) {
                    $(".n-titles:nth-child(" + i + ")").removeAttr("id");
                }
                $(".n-items:nth-child(3)").css("height", "370");
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/of7r6q6c/1/)

Answer (score 1):

So, in your JavaScript, you are adding height values inline to your markup (either 0px or 370px. These inline styles will, by default, override whatever is in your stylesheet. This is how CSS specificity works:

> ...inline style rules always have the highest specificity, the only
>   way to overwrite them within the CSS cascade is to use the !important
>   statement on the relevant declarations—an approach that creates a
>   maintenance nightmare. (via [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/specificity/))

Sitepoint has also given you the solution to this problem (well, the quickest fix, if not the best); add an `!important` flag to your hover declaration:

```
.n-titles:nth-child(n+2):hover + .n-items {
    /* Important needed here to override inline CSS generated by JS */
    height: 370px!important;
}
```

While the above code solves your initial problem, you may want to explore if, instead of inline styles, you can get the same sort of functionality by instead using JS to apply classes that identify the accordion's state (like `is-open` `is-closed`), which then allow you to control all the CSS from within your stylesheet.